# x64 va_list in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, stack, 64-bit, win64, variadic-functions

I have a class non-static member function, and it has variable arguments, I'm compiling on Visual Studio 2005, with the 64-bit runtime, on 64-bit Windows.

```
void Class::Foo(void* ptr,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,ptr);
    float f=va_arg(args,float);
    va_end(args)
}
```

I'm expecting a float, I pass a float to the function. But when I debug - I don't get the float I've passed. In fact - it's being received by the function as a 64-bit double! I have to do this:

```
double d=va_arg(args,double);
float f=(float)d;
```

Now I know Win64 likes to pass parameters in registers, and casts floats when it does this, shouldn't a va_list always be on the stack?

According to [most references](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/other/va_arg), I should have just a clean stack full of the passed parameters.

My question is: is this correct behaviour, or a bug? And if it's a bug, is it my bug, or Microsoft's?

I have the defines WIN64 and _M_AMD64, and WIN32 is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the C++ standard here, but it follows the C standard in this matter. C99, 6.5.2.2p7 says

> If the expression that denotes the
>   called function has a type that does
>   include a prototype, the arguments are
>   implicitly converted, as if by
>   assignment, to the types of the
>   corresponding parameters, taking the
>   type of each parameter to be the
>   unqualified version of its declared
>   type. The ellipsis notation in a
>   function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after
>   the last declared parameter. The
>   default argument promotions are
>   performed on trailing arguments.

So for your float argument, "default argument promotions" are performed.
These are defined in p6 as

> If the expression that denotes the
>   called function has a type that does
>   not include a prototype, the integer
>   promotions are performed on each
>   argument, and arguments that have type
>   float are promoted to double. These
>   are called the default argument
>   promotions. [...]

So all floats are converted to double when being passed to an ellipse. VS apparently conforms in this respect, and the bug is in your code, which shouldn't use `float` in `va_arg`.

Comment: I think this is correct. Although there's nothing in the C++ standard about "default argument promotions", in the absence of that I believe that the C standard applies. As I understand it, the text you quoted says that because an argument passed to a variable-argument function is not prototyped (because you can't prototype the types when they're variable), they are always promoted to the biggest relevant type - int or double. Odd behaviour I think - but apparently these are the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a VC++ x64 bug.

[FIX: The va_arg function returns an incorrect value in a Visual C++ 2005 application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920285)